# stringbuilder or streamwriter overwriting information

Tags: c#, csv, stringbuilder, streamwriter

I'm sending a couple of dictionaries to a streamwriter and a stringbuilder, only one of the dictionary's info is displayed in my output file though. I'm not sure what to do to get everything to output at once, code is below, thanks!

```
public void RunReport()
{
    CSVProfileCreate(genderKeys, genderValues);
    CSVProfileCreate(ageKeys, ageValues);
}

public void CSVProfileCreate<T>(Dictionary<T, string> columns, Dictionary<T, int> data)
{
    using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("c:/temp/testoutputprofile.csv"))
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        IEnumerable<string> col = columns.Values.AsEnumerable();
        IEnumerable<int> dat = data.Values.AsEnumerable();

        for (int i = 0; i < col.Count(); i++)
        {
            output.Append(col.ElementAt(i));
            output.Append(",");
            output.Append(dat.ElementAt(i));
            output.Append(",");
            output.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        write.Write(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ryan are you trying to write to a local machine or a remote location shouldn't the path be @"c:\temp\testoutput.csv"

Comment: thx, I'll get that changed.

Comment: how come you are using both StreamWriter and StringBuilder..? Instead of using StringBuilder, try using TextWriter

Comment: Streamwriter to create the file and open the stream for writing, stringbuilder to create the output. Should I only be using one or the other?

Comment: it works but you could have used TextWriter or StreamWriter but you can read about all your options here [How to write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling

```
write.Flush();
```

after the write.

EDIT:

Sorry, just read your question  again,

try:

```
using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("c:/temp/testoutputprofile.csv", true))
```

Comment: Sort of worke :) lol, now I'm seeing the one set of information being input twice into the file though.

Comment: make sure you properly dispose of the `StringBuilder output` output object instance as well at the end of your code when you're finished